# How dos CUDA affect on deep learning performance?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, deep-learning, gpu

I am now working on Deep learning, with GPU-based Keras.

I found that there is a critical problem in reproducibility.

Even though seed number is fixed and shuffle in model.fit is turned off,

There is still some reproducibility problem.

I found that GPU has those problem, when one is trying Convolution Network.

I wonder if the problem still holds for network with only ReLU.

If not, may I ask you some advice to get a fine reproductibility?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you using cuDNN with back-propagation? It's non-deterministic by design: http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/sandbox/cuda/dnn.html but you can change the options at the cost of performance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am using cuDNN with back-propagation. Does it still matter in tensorflow backend? And I understood that it only matters when using the convolution network, cudnnConvolutionBackwardFilter and cudnnConvolutionBackwardData. Please tell me if there is some misundertstanding. Thank you